# Dynamically substitue pattern with env variable with bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a file `file.txt` with this content: `Hi {YOU}, it's {ME}`

I would like to dynamically create a new file `file1.txt` like this

```
YOU=John
ME=Leonardo
cat ./file.txt | sed 'SED_COMMAND_HERE' > file1.txt
```

which content would be: `Hi John, it's Leonardo`

The sed command I tried so far is like this `s#{\([A-Z]*\)}#'"$\1"'#g` but the "substitution" part doesn't work correctly, it prints out `Hi $YOU, it's $ME`

Comment: Those duplicates assume that I already know the name of the variable, but I have already solved that way. I would like that to be dynamic (i.e. I can add env variables and placeholder, without changing the `sed` command)

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk with 2 files.

```
$> cat file.txt
Hi {YOU}, it's {ME}

$> cat repl.txt
YOU=John
ME=Leonardo

$> awk -F= 'FNR==NR{a["{" $1 "}"]=$2; next} {for (i in a) gsub(i,a[i])}1' repl.txt file.txt
Hi John, it's Leonardo
```

- First `awk` command goes through replacement file and stores each key-value in an array `a` be wrapping keys with `{` and `}`.
- In second iteration we just replace each key by value in actual file.

**Update:**

To do this without creating repl.txt you can use `process substitution**:

```
awk -F= 'FNR==NR{a["{" $1 "}"]=$2; next} {
   for (i in a) gsub(i,a[i])} 1' <(( set -o posix ; set ) | grep -E '^(YOU|ME)=') file.txt
```

Comment: This works but I need to use a single file, and use env bash variables

Comment: To do this without creating `repl.txt` you can do: `awk -F= 'FNR==NR{a["{" $1 "}"]=$2; next} {for (i in a) gsub(i,a[i])}1' <(( set -o posix ; set ) | grep -E '^(YOU|ME)=')  file.txt` (see updated)

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` utility can do multiple things to each input line:

```
$ sed -e "s/{YOU}/$YOU/" -e "s/{ME}/$ME/" inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

This assumes that `{YOU}` and `{ME}` occurs only once each on the line, otherwise, just add `g` (`"s/{YOU}/$YOU/g"` etc.)

Comment: This is what I am doing now, but I want it to be dynamic, so that I can add placeholders and env variable without changing the `sed` command script